# store custom value of v-select in vue 3

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I have a dropdown in my component which shows options from `chambers` model which has attributes (`location,address,phone` etc). Now in my `schedules` table I store only the `chamber_id` but when I go to edit mode, the label doesn't show the `location` as dropdown, it shows the `chamber_id`, since that is what is saved in the `schedules` table. I want the dropdown to show the `location` instead of the id value saved in DB, how do I do that?

```
<v-select
    v-model="schedule.chamber_id"
    :options="chambers"
    label="location"
></v-select>
```

Here the dropdown option shows `3` but I want it to show the `location` against record 3 of `chambers` table
[image]

Comment: Is that vuetify v-select? Vuetify next is not production ready at all. V-SELECT is particularly volatile and changes with every beta release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `vue-select`, this would be good of you to clarify, since vuetify also has `v-select`, however their APIs vary a little.

`vue-select` allow passing array of strings or numbers

```html
<!-- array of strings or numbers -->
<v-select :options="['Canada', 'United States']" v-model="myValue"/>
```

Whatever (string or number) you pass to `v-model` will be the selected value, even if it is not available in options.

In order to distinguish the value from label, you need to send an array of objects to `options`. The default for label is `label` but you can override it with the `label` prop.

```html
<script>
options = [{label: 'Canada', id: 1}, {label:'!Canada', id: 0];
</script>
<!-- or, an array of objects -->
<v-select :options="options" v-model="myValue"/>
```

In this case, `myValue` will be mapped to the entire object, which is still not   what you want. To solve this with `vue-select`, you need to make use of the reduce function.

```html
<v-select :options="options" :reduce="sel => sel.id" label="label" v-model="myValue"/>
```

Now, if you have `myValue` equal to `1`, the selected option would say `Canada`

source/docs:

- using options:
  https://vue-select.org/guide/options.html#options-prop
- using values:
  https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#transforming-selections